# C++, If...Else with strings and special characters

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, internationalization

I was trying to create a simple program to help my students to train German irregular verbs, but I have had problems with special characters and If statement. Basically it does not recognise the ä ö ü and ß, and output is therefore the Else statement (¨Nicht Gut"). How could I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;


int main () {
   
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "German");
   string Antwort1;
   string Antwort2;
   string Antwort3;
   getline(cin, str);
   
   cout << str;

   cout << "Präsens von BEHALTEN (du)" << endl;
   cin >> Antwort1;
       
   if (Antwort1 == "behältst") {
       cout << "Gut!" << endl;
   }
   else {
       cout << "Nicht Gut" << endl;
   }
   
   cout << "Präsens von BEHALTEN (er/sie/es/man) " << endl;
   cin >> Antwort1;
       
   if (Antwort1 == "behält") {
       cout << "Gut!" << endl;
   }
   else {
       cout << "Nicht Gut" << endl;
   }

   return 0;   
}
```

I tried with

```
if (Antwort1 == (LC_CTYPE, "German"),"behält")
```

but then it causes the contrary effect. Then every single string I write is valid ("Gut").

Comment: I'd check the encoding of the string from `getline`, then try to use a proper `basic_string<>` with the proper [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).  You could also check out libraries to deal with unicode.

Comment: My guess would be your string literals are using a different encoding to the ones you are reading from `cin`. `Antwort1 == (LC_CTYPE, "German"),"behält"` is exactly the same as just  `"behält"`, the comma operator possibly doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: This is maybe not the answer you're looking for, but I know that, in German language, 'ä' is equal to 'ae'. So, you might replace 'ä' with 'ae' (if present) and then check against 'behaeltst', and you won't have the problem with the umlaut.

Comment: As an aside, `<conio.h>` is not a standard C++ (or C, for that matter) header file. It doesn't much matter here, since you don't seem to be using it, but I would advise against ever including that header. On a related note, the C++ version of `<locale.h>` is `<clocale>`.

Comment: The standard `<iostream>` functions are all oriented towards ASCII characters; you may need to use the wide-character versions of those functions and objects, e.g., `wcin
`, `wcout`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My answer applies to the **Windows 10 console** using the classic default Command Prompt (I haven't tried it with other systems like PowerShell, nor I have tried these experiments on Linux yet).

It seems to me that, as of today (23 February 2022), Windows 10's Command Prompt and the Microsoft C/C++ Runtime of VS2019 **don't support Unicode UTF-8 well**: See, for example, [this blog post](https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2017/08/22/printing-utf-8-text-to-the-windows-console/) showing a CRT crash you get when trying to call:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
```

and printing UTF-8 text using `std::cout`.

In my experience, you can make Unicode work in Windows Command Prompt using **Unicode UTF-16**. You can still use UTF-8 in your C++ application, but you have to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 at the Windows boundaries.

I modified your code to use Unicode UTF-16, and the code seems to work correctly when compiled with Visual Studio 2019, and executed inside the Windows Command Prompt:

```
// Used for _setmode calls
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Console I/O with Unicode UTF-16 wcin, wcout and wstring
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::wcin;
using std::wcout;
using std::wstring;

int main() {
    // Enable Unicode UTF-16 console input/output
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);

    wcout << L"Präsens von BEHALTEN (du) \n";
    wstring Antwort1;
    wcin >> Antwort1;

    if (Antwort1 == L"behältst") {
        wcout << L"Gut! \n";
    } else {
        wcout << L"Nicht Gut \n";
    }
}
```

Note the use of `L"..."` to represent UTF-16 string literals, and the use of `wchar_t`-based `std::wcout`, `std::wcin`, and `std::wstring` instead of the `char`-based `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::string`.